# Populating dynamic form controls with data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am working on an Angular 2 project where I am creating input fields dynamically on button click. I am taking the help of FormArray for the same. The creation of fields and data submission is working fine but when I am trying to populate the fields with some pre-defined data then it doesn't work. I have created a plunker for my issue.
https://plnkr.co/edit/PCFD43GK91zo2ivQ9lf7?p=preview
Here I want to populate the fields on the view with the data in the object itemData. For easy reference, following is Angular code -

```
//our root app component
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<hr>
              <div>  
                <form [formGroup]="orderForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(orderForm.value)">
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <label>Customer Name</label>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="customerName"/>
                      <small *ngIf="IsValidField('customerName')" class="text-danger">
                          Customer Name is required
                      </small>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div>
                      <label>Customer Email</label>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="email"/>
                      <small *ngIf="IsValidField('email')" class="text-danger">
                          Email is required
                      </small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br/>
                  <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i = index;">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                      <div>
                        <label>Item Name</label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name"/>
                        <small *ngIf="IsValidField('name',i)" class="text-danger">
                          Item Name is required
                        </small>
                      </div>
                      <br/>
                      <div>
                        <label>Item Description</label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description"/>
                        <small *ngIf="IsValidField('description',i)" class="text-danger">
                          Description is required
                        </small>
                      </div>
                      <br/>
                      <div>
                        <label>Item Price</label>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="price" placeholder="Item price"/>
                        <small *ngIf="IsValidField('price',i)" class="text-danger">
                          Price is required
                        </small>
                      </div>
                      <br/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit">Save</button>
                  <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add More</button>
                  <button type="button" (click)="loadItems()">Load Items</button>
                </form>
              <div>`,
})

export class App {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {  }

  public orderForm: FormGroup;
  public formSubmitAttempt: boolean;
  public itemData:any=`{
    "customerName":"Customer 1","email":"abc@xyz.com",
    "items":[{"name":"Item 1","description":"Item 1 Descr","price":"100"},
            {"name":"Item 2","description":"Item 2 Descr","price":"200"},
            {"name":"Item 3","description":"Item 3 Descr","price":"300"}]
  }`;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      customerName: ['',[Validators.required]],
      email: ['',[Validators.required]],
      items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem()])
    });
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(10)]],
      description: '',
      price: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("[(0-9)]*")]]
    });
  }

  public loadItems(){
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      customerName: [this.itemData.customerName,[Validators.required]],
      email: [this.itemData.email,[Validators.required]],
      items: this.itemData.items
    });
  }

  get items(): FormArray {
    return this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  };

  addItem(): void {
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }

  public OnSubmit(formValue: any) {
    this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(formValue));
  }

  public IsValidField(field: string, i?:number) {
    if(i!=null) {
      var f = this.orderForm
        .get('items') //retrieve items FormArray
        .get(i.toString()) //retrieve items FormGroup
        .get(field); //retrieve items form field

      return (f.invalid && f.touched) || (f.invalid && this.formSubmitAttempt);
    } else {
      return (this.orderForm.get(field).invalid && this.orderForm.get(field).touched) || (this.orderForm.get(field).invalid && this.formSubmitAttempt);            
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements inside a formArray has to be formGroups, not just an object.

Run your `this.itemData.items` through the createItems function you already have when trying to assign default values to your formArray.

```
public loadItems(){
  this.orderForm.patchValue({
    customerName: this.itemData.customerName,
    email: this.itemData.email
  });

  this.itemData.forEach((item) => {
    (<FormArray>this.orderForm.get('items')).push(this.createItem(item));
  });

}
```

No need to recreate the form when data comes from a service, just patchValues and update form accordingly.

PS: you need to modify createItems to take some input data and return the formGroup with data.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit. I tried it like this

public loadItems(){
   this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        customerName: [this.itemData.customerName,[Validators.required]],
        email: [this.itemData.email,[Validators.required]],
        items: this.formBuilder.array([this.itemData.items])
      });
 }
But it didn't worked. [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PCFD43GK91zo2ivQ9lf7?p=preview)
It throws following error 
Cannot find control with path: 'items -> 0 -> name'

Comment: you just copied what is in the post, of course isnt gonna work, as formArray needs formGroups, this.itemData.items is just an object

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped. Its working now. The only problem is when the data is populated, the previous controls (created by default on init) also remains there. Any work around for this ?
[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PCFD43GK91zo2ivQ9lf7?p=preview)

Comment: Any work around for my last query ? Please have a look to the [updated plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/PCFD43GK91zo2ivQ9lf7?p=preview)

Comment: I think what you have to change in ngOnInit is this: ```items: this.formBuilder.array([])``` note the empty array as initialization

Comment: Hey bro, I rather handled it from the loadItems() methods by resetting the form like this. [Updated Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/PCFD43GK91zo2ivQ9lf7?p=preview)
Is it a good approach ?

Comment: You should never recreate the form as you can mutate its state with *patchValue* or *updateValue* methods accordingly, i'd init the form as minimal as possible in *ngOnInit* then keep the update/patch as needed. you can replace clean the array on *loadItems* before start pushing, so no need to recreate the entire form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156284/discussion-between-sonicd300-and-amit-anand).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the definition of your itemData try to delete the **`** to define the object:

```
public itemData:any={
    "customerName":"Customer 1","email":"abc@xyz.com",
    "items":[{"name":"Item 1","description":"Item 1 Descr","price":"100"},
            {"name":"Item 2","description":"Item 2 Descr","price":"200"},
            {"name":"Item 3","description":"Item 3 Descr","price":"300"}]
};
```

and in your `loadItems` method add brackets to assign the value of `items` :

```
public loadItems(){
   this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        customerName: [this.itemData.customerName,[Validators.required]],
        email: [this.itemData.email,[Validators.required]],
        items: [this.itemData.items]
      });
}
```

hope it helps :)